# Problemas en la Validación PHP-JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, sql, sql-server, validación

Tengo el siguiente código que lo que hace es enviar por un formulario a través del método `get` a una pagina de **php** los valores de 1 `combobox` y 3 `textbox`.

Con el objetivo de generar un archivo **Excel** de acuerdo a los parámetros que el usuario facilita.

**Código Javascript:**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  let btnGenerar = document.getElementById('Generar');

$('#Generar').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

let selectVal = $("#controlselect").val();
let fInicial = $('#txtfecha').val();
let fFinal = $('#txtfechafinal').val();
let busqueda = $('#busqueda').val();


window.location.href= `mipagina.php?selectVal=${selectVal}&fInicial=${fInicial}&fFinal=${fFinal}&busqueda=${busqueda}`;

});

})
</script>
```

**Código PHP (`mipagina.php`):**

```
<?php
    $v1 = $_GET['selectVal'];
    $v2 = $_GET['fInicial'];
    $v3 = $_GET['fFinal'];
    $v4 = $_GET['busqueda'];

if($v1 == 1 && $v2 == null && $v3 == null && $v4 != null )
{
    $consulta = "aqui coloco mi query";
    $ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($con,$consulta);
    $NumeroFilas = sqlsrv_has_rows($ejecutar);

    if($NumeroFilas == 0)
    {
        echo('<script> alert("No existen registros con los datos solicitados"); 
        window.history.back();</script>');

    }

    else
   {
     //Aqui va el código que genera el Excel
   }

}

?>
```

Motivo a que el código es muy largo y ahorrar tiempo, lo que hace es:

De acuerdo a los valores que se le pasan al **php** , este va a generar el **excel** o validar el error de que alguno de los datos que ingresa están incorrectos y mostrarlo al usuario.

Actualmente todo lo hace, mientras el usuario ingrese valores que existen en mi Base de Datos, como buena práctica , le quiero colocar una simple validación que 
muestre un mensaje al momento de que el usuario ingrese un valor incorrecto.

Yo lo inserté como muestro en el código, y valida cuando el valor ingresado es inválido y retorna a la página principal sin problemas, pero al momento de colocar un valor correcto, me sigue mostrando el mensaje del error y por supuesto no genera mi archivo **excel**.

Me gustaría saber cual es el motivo del error y de ser así, facilitarme el código de como sería o si es necesario hacer uno nuevo.

Agradecido de Antemano!

Comment: Creo que te respondes a ti mismo. Si te sigue mostrando el mensaje de error con valores correctos es que `$NumeroFilas == 0`, luego la consulta es incorrecta. Revísala

Comment: Habrá un problema en la lógica?¿

Comment: Desconozco la consulta que realizas, pero está claro que o bien es errónea o no tiene los datos que buscas puesto que siempre devuelve 0 filas

Comment: Yo quito el condicional y la consulta se hace , es lo irónico.

Comment: Averigua el valor de ' $NumeroFilas` cuando le pasas valores correctos, ahí está el problema

Comment: Perfecto, voy a verificar a ver.

Comment: Gracias igual por tu apoyo @RogerTorné

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví, el problema fue simplemente que las líneas de código estaban mal ubicadas de la librería PHPEXCEL, las tenía ubicada al inicio del condicional y luego las coloqué dentro de mi else quedando algo así:

**EL CODIGO JAVASCRIPT QUEDÓ IGUAL**

**Lo que cambió fue mi  CODIGO PHP**

```
<?php
    $v1 = $_GET['selectVal'];
    $v2 = $_GET['fInicial'];
    $v3 = $_GET['fFinal'];
    $v4 = $_GET['busqueda'];

if($v1 == 1 && $v2 == null && $v3 == null && $v4 != null )
{
    $consulta = "aqui coloco mi query";
    $ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($con,$consulta);
    $NumeroFilas = sqlsrv_has_rows($ejecutar);

    if($NumeroFilas == 0)
    {
        echo('<script> alert("No existen registros con los datos solicitados"); 
        window.history.back();</script>');

    }

    else
   {
     //Aqui va el código que genera el Excel
        header("Content-Type: application/vdn.ms-excel");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Excel.xls');
        $excel = new PHPExcel();

        $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $pagina = $excel->getActiveSheet();


        while($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($ejecutar))
        {

         //Aqui dibujo los títulos de las columnas del documento excel en las celdas indicadas
            $pagina->setCellValue('C1','ID');
            $pagina->setCellValue('D1','Producto');
            $pagina->setCellValue('E1','Cliente');
            $pagina->setCellValue('F1','Telefono');
            $pagina->setCellValue('G1','Numero de Tarjeta');
            $pagina->setCellValue('H1','Cedula');
            $pagina->setCellValue('I1','Fecha de la Consulta');

            //Aqui van las variables que guardan los resultados del query
            $id = $fila['ID'];
            $Producto = $fila['NombreProducto'];
            $Cliente = $fila['Cliente'];
            $Telefono = $fila['NumeroTelefono'];
            $NumeroTarjeta = $fila['NumeroTarjeta'];
            $Cedula = $fila['Cedula'];
            $FechaConsulta = $fila['FechaConsulta'];

          //Aqui lleno cada celda con las variables anteriores.
            $pagina->setCellValue('C'.$j,$id);
            $pagina->setCellValue('D'.$j,$Producto);
            $pagina->setCellValue('E'.$j,$Cliente);
            $pagina->setCellValue('F'.$j,$Telefono);
            $pagina->setCellValue('G'.$j,$NumeroTarjeta);
            $pagina->setCellValue('H'.$j,$Cedula);
            $pagina->setCellValue('I'.$j,$FechaConsulta);

            $j++;
            $i++;

        }   


        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel,'Excel5');

//Colocar estos dos códigos en este orden para evitar que el archivo excel genere la data con formato inválido, muchas veces ocurre que a pesar de que el query este bien y la lógica también , el archivo se crea en forma errada.

        ob_end_clean();
        ob_start();

//
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
   }

}

?>
```