# Error de Consulta. Problemas de Concatenación

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código , me está trayendo error de la consulta:
`sqlsrv_query() expects parameter` y `sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter`

A pesar de que la consulta es larga, lo que hace el código es simplemente dibujar una tabla en base a los parámetros que reciba por formulario mi página de php a través del método GET

El entra en el condicional , pero genera error en la consulta

```
<table class='table' id='tabla'>

<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
    $v1 = $_GET['selectVal'];
    $v2 = $_GET['fInicial'];
    $v3 = $_GET['fFinal'];
    $v4 = $_GET['busqueda'];

    if($v1 == 1 && $v2 != null && $v3 != null && $v4 != null)
    {

    echo("
                        <thead>
                            <th>Teléfono</th>
                            <th>Cédula</th>
                            <th>Beneficiario</th>
                            <th>Tarjeta</th>
                            <th>Cliente</th>
                            <th>Producto</th>
                            <th>Fecha de Consulta</th>
                        </thead>
");
        $consulta = "
                    declare @Fecha_ini  datetime 
                    declare @Fecha_fin datetime 

                    set @Fecha_ini = '$v2'
                    set @Fecha_fin = '$v3'


                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000 
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS   NumeroTelefono,
                                CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Cedula,1,2),'.',SUBSTRING(Cedula,3,3),'.',SUBSTRING(Cedula,6,6)) AS Cedula,
                                CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido) AS Nombre,
                                NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta,
                                tarjetas.cliente as Cliente,
                                Producto.nombre as Producto,
                                Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id =   Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto

                            where LEN(Cedula) = '8'  and replace(cedula,'.','') like '%$v4%' and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)

                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.id asc) T

                        union all

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-   ',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS NumeroTelefono
                                ,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Cedula,1,1),'.',SUBSTRING(Cedula,3,3),'.',SUBSTRING(Cedula,5,5)) AS   Cedula
                                ,CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido)  AS Nombre
                                ,NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta
                                ,tarjetas.cliente as Cliente
                                ,Producto.nombre as Producto
                                ,Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id =   Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto

                            where LEN(Cedula) = '7'  and replace(cedula,'.','')  like '%$v4%' and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)
                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.id asc) T1

                        union all

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000 
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS   NumeroTelefono
                                ,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Cedula,1,3),'.',SUBSTRING(Cedula,4,6)) AS Cedula
                                ,CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido)      AS Nombre
                                ,NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta
                                ,tarjetas.cliente as Cliente
                                ,Producto.nombre as Producto
                                ,Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha 
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id =       Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto

                            where LEN(Cedula) = '6'  and replace(cedula,'.','')  like '%$v4%' and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)
                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.id asc) T2 

                        union all

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000 
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS   NumeroTelefono
                                ,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Cedula,1,2),'.',SUBSTRING(Cedula,3,5)) AS Cedula
                                ,CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido) AS Nombre
                                ,NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta
                                ,tarjetas.cliente as Cliente
                                ,Producto.nombre as Producto
                                ,Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id = Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto
                            where LEN(Cedula) = '5'  and replace(cedula,'.','')  like '%$v4%' and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)
                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.id asc) T3

                        union all

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000 
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS   NumeroTelefono
                                ,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Cedula,1,1),'.',SUBSTRING(Cedula,2,4)) AS Cedula
                                ,CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido) AS Nombre
                                ,NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta
                                ,tarjetas.cliente as Cliente
                                ,Producto.nombre as Producto
                                ,Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id = Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto
                            where LEN(Cedula) = '4'  and replace(cedula,'.','')  like '%$v4%' and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)
                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.id asc) T4

                        union all

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000 
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS   NumeroTelefono
                                ,Cedula AS Cedula
                                ,CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido) AS Nombre
                                ,NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta
                                ,tarjetas.cliente as Cliente
                                ,Producto.nombre as Producto
                                ,Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id = Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto

                            where LEN(Cedula) = '3'  and replace(cedula,'.','')  like '%$v4%' and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)
                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.id asc) T5

                        union all

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000 
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS NumeroTelefono
                                ,Cedula AS Cedula
                                ,CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido) AS Nombre
                                ,NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta
                                ,tarjetas.cliente as Cliente
                                ,Producto.nombre as Producto
                                ,Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id = Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto

                            where LEN(Cedula) = '2'  and replace(cedula,'.','')  like '%$v4%' and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)
                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.id asc) T6

                        union all

                        Select * From 
                            (Select top 10000000 
                                CONCAT('0',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,6,3),'-',SUBSTRING(NumeroTelefono,9,12)) AS   NumeroTelefono
                                ,Cedula AS Cedula
                                ,CONCAT(TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerNombre,' ',TarjetahabienteCliente.PrimerApellido) AS Nombre
                                ,NumeroTarjeta as Tarjeta
                                ,tarjetas.cliente as Cliente
                                ,Producto.nombre as Producto
                                ,Convert(varchar(10),FechaConsulta,103) as Fecha
                            from Operaciones.RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS 

                            inner join tarjetas on tarjetas.Numero = RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.NumeroTarjeta 
                            inner join  Operaciones.TarjetahabienteCliente on TarjetahabienteCliente.id = Tarjetas.TarjetahabienteId
                            inner join Producto on Producto.id = tarjetas.Producto
                            where LEN(Cedula) = '1'  and replace(cedula,'.','')  like '%$v4%' and FechaConsulta between @Fecha_ini and (@Fecha_fin + 1)
                            order by RegistroConsultaSaldoSMS.id asc) T7    

                            ";

    $ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($con,$consulta);
    $i = 0;

            while($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($ejecutar))
            {

                $NumeroTelefono = $fila['NumeroTelefono'];
                $Cedula = $fila['Cedula'];
                $Nombre = $fila['Nombre'];
                $NumeroTarjeta = $fila['Tarjeta'];
                $Cliente = $fila['Cliente'];
                $Producto   = $fila['Producto'];
                $FechaConsulta = $fila['Fecha'];
                $i++;

            echo("<tbody>
                            <td>$NumeroTelefono</td>
                            <td>$Cedula</td>
                            <td>$Nombre</td>
                            <td>$NumeroTarjeta</td>
                            <td>$Cliente</td>
                            <td>$Producto</td>
                            <td>$FechaConsulta</td>
                            </tbody>
                        "
                    );
        }   

    }
    ?>  

</table>
```

Ya verifiqué , los datos y las variables y estoy seguro que funciona
correctamente.

Estoy viendo que el error posiblemente pueda ser por **mala concatenación de los elementos HTML Y PHP**

Quisiera saber si estoy en lo correcto y si los estoy, pueden ayudarme a corregir ese de **error de concatenación**

Por supuesto si es otro **error** con su explicación y el código por favor.

Agradecido de Antemano.

Comment: Ve haciendo la consulta poco a poco para acotar el problema. Como bien dices, la consulta es realmente grande, por lo que intenta hacer select a select por separado, para ver si es un problema de concatenación o el clásico ;

Comment: Puedes intentar mostrar el error para que sepas donde está el problema haciendo algo así: `if ($ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($con,$consulta) ) {//codigo de lectura con el while, etc } else { print_r (sqlsrv_errors()); }`ahí te mostrará por qué falla la consulta. Otra cosa que debes verificar es **que la conexión sea correcta**.

Comment: Yo coloqué la misma consulta directo en mi gestor, colocándole por supuesto datos existentes para ver si era problema del código y no , trae la información correspondiente.

Comment: imprime la variable $consulta y ejecutala en tu sqlsrv, verifica que no existan errores, si todo esta ok, entonces muestra el error que te genera el .php, en caso no se muestre el error, puedes verificar en tu archivo log de errores.

Comment: @A.Cedano hice lo que me indicaste y me salió este error 

**Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )**

Comment: Puedes pulsar en [edit] para agregar el error en la pregunta. Será de gran ayuda para detectar el problema.

Comment: @Fergush si te refieres correrla por el gestor, no creo , porque la consulta la corrí en él , utilizando datos ya ingresados y trae la información deseada

Comment: ¿Seguro que tu conexión es correcta? Parece que no lo es, rodea el código de esto, antes de pasar la consulta: `if ($con) {  // tu código de pasar la consulta y demás } else { echo "La conexión no es válida"; } ` Ahí veremos si pasa algo con tu conexión.

Comment: @Fergush imprimí la variable consulta y me está asignando las variables, no creo que sea la conexión.

Comment: El error `An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query` ocurre casi siempre porque le pasas una conexión inválida, por tanto, descarta esa posibilidad. No es cuestión de pensar *no creo que sea esto o aquello*, cuando escribes código debes controlar y prever cualquier eventualidad y una de ellas es una conexión nula, porque las credenciales son erróneas, porque se cayó el servidor de BD o lo que sea. Por tanto debes controlar: `if ($con) { // tu código de pasar la consulta y demás } else { echo "La conexión no es válida"; }` Y asegúrate que se llama `$con` y no de otro modo.

Comment: @A.Cedano perfecto déjame verificar.

Comment: Problema resuelto colegas. 

Solución Final: Me falto importar mi archivo de conexión. 

Gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/315773/problemas-en-la-validaci%c3%b3n-php-javascript?noredirect=1#comment573134_315773)

Si pueden pasarse por aquí y dar sus aportes , se los agradecería por igual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error `An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query...` ocurre casi siempre porque le pasas una conexión inválida, por tanto, tienes que descartar esa posibilidad y cualquier otra escribiendo un código controlado.

Por ejemplo:

```
#Controlar estado de la conexión
if ($con) {
    //Escribir la consulta ...

    #Controlar estado de la consulta    
    if ($ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($con,$consulta) ) {

        //codigo de lectura con el while, etc 

    } else { 

        #Esto es para fines de depuración, lo puedes (debes) cambiar por un mensaje personalizado
        print_r (sqlsrv_errors()); 

    }

} else {

    echo "No hay conexión";

}
```

Siempre que programes debes prever todas las eventualidades. Es un error programar pensando que siempre las cosas irán bien. El servidor puede estar caído, puede haber un problema de red, pueden ocurrir varias cosas que deben estar reflejadas en el código, mostrando mensajes adecuados para esos casos. Como consejo, evita mostrar mensajes internos de la base de datos y demás, cámbialos por mensajes personalizados que informen al usuario. El control de errores en los programas es de suma importancia.